# ASP.Net 4.5 - Web Method Does Not Get Called From JQuery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have set break points in the C# code and the web method is not invoked. I should see four rows returned from the database.

I do not get any errors - the only thing I see in the console is an error on the the length (in the javascript for loop ie i < data.d.length).

Relevant Code

**TestApp.aspx.cs**

```
    namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class User
    {
        public int?   TestID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TestApp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        [WebMethod]
        public static User[] Get()
        {
            try
            {
                List<User> details = FetchData("sp_LoadData", null);
                return details.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

**TestApp.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TestApp.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.TestApp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="TestApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1">

                        <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="1" width="100%" border="1">
                            <thead style="border: solid thin;">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>First name</th>
                                    <th>Last name</th>
                                    <th>Email</th>
                                    <th>Phone</th>
                                    <th>Delete</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                        </table>
```

**TestApp.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    BindGrid();

function BindGrid() {
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();
    t.rows().remove().draw();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "TestApp.aspx/Get",
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",

        success: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                //debugger;
                t.row.add([
                            '<a class="table-edit" onclick="showRecord(' + data.d[i].TestID + ');">' + data.d[i].FirstName + '</a>',
                            data.d[i].LastName,
                            data.d[i].Email,
                            data.d[i].Phone,
                            '<button type="button" onclick="deleteRecord(' + data.d[i].TestID + ');">Delete</button>'
                ]).draw(false);
            }
        },
        error: function (result) {
            debugger;
            alert("Error");
        }
    });
};
```

[image: Here is the console]

[image: Network]

Comment: So you're not get any errors in the Console - what about the Network tab? Are you seeing the call made to the WebService?

Comment: You may want to throw a `console.log("Data: " + data)` statement as the first line in your `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

"I do not get any errors - the only thing I see in the console is an error on the the length", so you DO get an error :)

When you are checking the length, you are assuming there is always an array defined as 'd' in data.  You should add a check to validate your assumptions:

```
if (data && data.d && data.d.length) {
  for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
     ...
```

Comment: You are correct, Rob. I guess I was talking about not getting an error as to why the Web Method was not being called (title of my Post).

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
[ScriptMethod]
```

Below [WebMethod]

Comment: You don't actually need this for a PageMethod... Only if you are using ASMX services.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that since you're passing in an empty object .NET is looking for a function defined like Get(object) not Get(). Try removing the below from your ajax call:

```
   data: "{}",
   dataType: "json",
```